# Show only one question with options not others after selection of language

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying the following code,but activate only one question and options in selection of language, not others. the code is:

```html
<html>
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    </head>
<body>
        <select class="selLang" onchange="SelectLang(this);" name="selLang">
            <option>Select Language</option>
            <option value="1">Hindi</option>
            <option value="2">English</option>
        </select>
        <script>
            function SelectLang(selLang){
                var idElement = selLang;
                var selectedValue = idElement.options[idElement.selectedIndex].value;
                if(selectedValue === "1"){
                    document.getElementById("hindiOptA").disabled = false;
                    document.getElementById("hindiOptB").disabled = false;
                    document.getElementById("hindiOptC").disabled = false;
                    document.getElementById("hindiOptD").disabled = false;
                    document.getElementById("engOptA").disabled = true;
                    document.getElementById("engOptB").disabled = true;
                    document.getElementById("engOptC").disabled = true;
                    document.getElementById("engOptD").disabled = true;
                }else if(selectedValue === "2"){
                    document.getElementById("hindiOptA").disabled = true;
                    document.getElementById("hindiOptB").disabled = true;
                    document.getElementById("hindiOptC").disabled = true;
                    document.getElementById("hindiOptD").disabled = true;
                    document.getElementById("engOptA").disabled = false;
                    document.getElementById("engOptB").disabled = false;
                    document.getElementById("engOptC").disabled = false;
                    document.getElementById("engOptD").disabled = false;
                }else{
                    document.getElementById("hindiOptA").disabled = true;
                    document.getElementById("hindiOptB").disabled = true;
                    document.getElementById("hindiOptC").disabled = true;
                    document.getElementById("hindiOptD").disabled = true;
                    document.getElementById("engOptA").disabled = true;
                    document.getElementById("engOptB").disabled = true;
                    document.getElementById("engOptC").disabled = true;
                    document.getElementById("engOptD").disabled = true;
                }
            }
        </script>
<fieldset>
            <label>If Selected Hindi Language</label><br>
            <label>प्रश्न संख्या एक. आपका फेवरेट रंग क्या है</label><br>
            लाल: <input type="radio" name="opt1" value="A" id="hindiOptA" disabled="true">
            नीला: <input type="radio" name="opt1" value="B" id="hindiOptB" disabled="true">
            भूरा: <input type="radio" name="opt1" value="C" id="hindiOptC" disabled="true">
            सफेद: <input type="radio" name="opt1" value="D" id="hindiOptD" disabled="true">
            <br><label>प्रश्न संख्या 2. आपको कौन सा रंग पसंद है</label><br>
            लाल: <input type="radio" name="opt2" value="A" id="hindiOptA" disabled="true">
            नीला: <input type="radio" name="opt2" value="B" id="hindiOptB" disabled="true">
            भूरा: <input type="radio" name="opt2" value="C" id="hindiOptC" disabled="true">
            सफेद: <input type="radio" name="opt2" value="D" id="hindiOptD" disabled="true">
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <label>If Select English Langauge</label>
            <br><label>Q1. What is your favorite color</label><br>
            Red: <input type="radio" name="opt1" value="A" id="engOptA" disabled="true">
            Blue: <input type="radio" name="opt1" value="B" id="engOptB" disabled="true">
            Brown: <input type="radio" name="opt1" value="C" id="engOptC" disabled="true">
            White: <input type="radio" name="opt1" value="D" id="engOptD" disabled="true">
            <br><label>Q2. Which color you like</label><br>
            Red: <input type="radio" name="opt2" value="A" id="engOptA" disabled="true">
            Blue: <input type="radio" name="opt2" value="B" id="engOptB" disabled="true">
            Brown: <input type="radio" name="opt2" value="C" id="engOptC" disabled="true">
            White: <input type="radio" name="opt2" value="D" id="engOptD" disabled="true">
        </fieldset>
        </body>  
        </html>
```

When i select Hindi language then only first question activated but not 2nd and other questions, similarly when select English then similar thing happened. Where i am wrong, please help me.

**Note:** Display both question set but activate only selected question set. My real code has written on JSP, and data is coming from MySQL database. Total questions in each sets are 45.

Comment: Read this https://www.educative.io/edpresso/class-and-id-selectors-in-css you get your answer.

Comment: the id field should be unique to each element

Answer (score 0):

You can use id selector for fieldset and based on the activated language you can set display property none and inherit for the intended fieldset.

Here I have added an id to both fieldsets and based on the selection I am displaying and hiding it.

Note: Each element should have a unique id if you don't want to face any error in the future. So do the change. If you won't change it, my solution will still work but you will face an error in processing the answers somewhere.

```html
<html>
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    </head>
<body>
        <select class="selLang" onchange="SelectLang(this);" name="selLang">
            <option>Select Language</option>
            <option value="1">Hindi</option>
            <option value="2">English</option>
        </select>
        <script>
            function SelectLang(selLang){
                var idElement = selLang;
                var selectedValue = idElement.options[idElement.selectedIndex].value;
                if(selectedValue === "1"){
                    document.getElementById("hindi").style.display = "inherit";
                    document.getElementById("english").style.display = "none";
       
                }else if(selectedValue === "2"){
                    document.getElementById("hindi").style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("english").style.display = "inherit";
                }
                else {
                    document.getElementById("hindi").style.display = "inherit";
                    document.getElementById("english").style.display = "inherit";
                }
            }
        </script>
<fieldset id="hindi">
            <label>If Selected Hindi Language</label><br>
            <label>प्रश्न संख्या एक. आपका फेवरेट रंग क्या है</label><br>
            लाल: <input type="radio" name="opt1" value="A" id="hindiOptA" disabled="true">
            नीला: <input type="radio" name="opt1" value="B" id="hindiOptB" disabled="true">
            भूरा: <input type="radio" name="opt1" value="C" id="hindiOptC" disabled="true">
            सफेद: <input type="radio" name="opt1" value="D" id="hindiOptD" disabled="true">
            <br><label>प्रश्न संख्या 2. आपको कौन सा रंग पसंद है</label><br>
            लाल: <input type="radio" name="opt2" value="A" id="hindiOptA" disabled="true">
            नीला: <input type="radio" name="opt2" value="B" id="hindiOptB" disabled="true">
            भूरा: <input type="radio" name="opt2" value="C" id="hindiOptC" disabled="true">
            सफेद: <input type="radio" name="opt2" value="D" id="hindiOptD" disabled="true">
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset id="english">
            <label>If Select English Langauge</label>
            <br><label>Q1. What is your favorite color</label><br>
            Red: <input type="radio" name="opt1" value="A" id="engOptA" disabled="true">
            Blue: <input type="radio" name="opt1" value="B" id="engOptB" disabled="true">
            Brown: <input type="radio" name="opt1" value="C" id="engOptC" disabled="true">
            White: <input type="radio" name="opt1" value="D" id="engOptD" disabled="true">
            <br><label>Q2. Which color you like</label><br>
            Red: <input type="radio" name="opt2" value="A" id="engOptA" disabled="true">
            Blue: <input type="radio" name="opt2" value="B" id="engOptB" disabled="true">
            Brown: <input type="radio" name="opt2" value="C" id="engOptC" disabled="true">
            White: <input type="radio" name="opt2" value="D" id="engOptD" disabled="true">
        </fieldset>
        </body>  
        </html>
```

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. But my problem is display both language questions but activate only one as per selection. My actual code and question and option data is coming from MySQL database and form have designed in JSP, Servlet and beans respectively. Above program is a sample program

Answer (score 0):

you can't use id for duplicate elements
id is a unique thing so use a unique id for every answer.

like below code.
Try this and if you have any doubts comment this answer!

```js
 function SelectLang(selLang){
                var idElement = selLang;
                var selectedValue = idElement.options[idElement.selectedIndex].value;
                if(selectedValue === "1"){
                    document.getElementById("hindiOptA").disabled = false;
                    document.getElementById("hindiOptB").disabled = false;
                    document.getElementById("hindiOptC").disabled = false;
                    document.getElementById("hindiOptD").disabled = false;
                    document.getElementById("hindiOptA2").disabled = false;
                    document.getElementById("hindiOptB2").disabled = false;
                    document.getElementById("hindiOptC2").disabled = false;
                    document.getElementById("hindiOptD2").disabled = false;
                    document.getElementById("engOptA").disabled = true;
                    document.getElementById("engOptB").disabled = true;
                    document.getElementById("engOptC").disabled = true;
                    document.getElementById("engOptD").disabled = true;
                    document.getElementById("engOptA2").disabled = true;
                    document.getElementById("engOptB2").disabled = true;
                    document.getElementById("engOptC2").disabled = true;
                    document.getElementById("engOptD2").disabled = true;
                }else if(selectedValue === "2"){
                    document.getElementById("hindiOptA").disabled = true;
                    document.getElementById("hindiOptB").disabled = true;
                    document.getElementById("hindiOptC").disabled = true;
                    document.getElementById("hindiOptD").disabled = true;
                    document.getElementById("hindiOptA2").disabled = true;
                    document.getElementById("hindiOptB2").disabled = true;
                    document.getElementById("hindiOptC2").disabled = true;
                    document.getElementById("hindiOptD2").disabled = true;
                    document.getElementById("engOptA").disabled = false;
                    document.getElementById("engOptB").disabled = false;
                    document.getElementById("engOptC").disabled = false;
                    document.getElementById("engOptD").disabled = false;
                    document.getElementById("engOptA2").disabled = false;
                    document.getElementById("engOptB2").disabled = false;
                    document.getElementById("engOptC2").disabled = false;
                    document.getElementById("engOptD2").disabled = false;

                }else{
                    document.getElementById("hindiOptA").disabled = true;
                    document.getElementById("hindiOptB").disabled = true;
                    document.getElementById("hindiOptC").disabled = true;
                    document.getElementById("hindiOptD").disabled = true;
                    document.getElementById("hindiOptA2").disabled = true;
                    document.getElementById("hindiOptB2").disabled = true;
                    document.getElementById("hindiOptC2").disabled = true;
                    document.getElementById("hindiOptD2").disabled = true;
                    document.getElementById("engOptA").disabled = true;
                    document.getElementById("engOptB").disabled = true;
                    document.getElementById("engOptC").disabled = true;
                    document.getElementById("engOptD").disabled = true;
                    document.getElementById("engOptA2").disabled = true;
                    document.getElementById("engOptB2").disabled = true;
                    document.getElementById("engOptC2").disabled = true;
                    document.getElementById("engOptD2").disabled = true;
                
                }
            }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    </head>
<body>
        <select class="selLang" onchange="SelectLang(this);" name="selLang">
            <option>Select Language</option>
            <option value="1">Hindi</option>
            <option value="2">English</option>
        </select>
        <script>

        </script>
<fieldset>
            <label>If Selected Hindi Language</label><br>
            <label>प्रश्न संख्या एक. आपका फेवरेट रंग क्या है</label><br>
            लाल: <input type="radio" name="opt1" value="A" id="hindiOptA" disabled="true">
            नीला: <input type="radio" name="opt1" value="B" id="hindiOptB" disabled="true">
            भूरा: <input type="radio" name="opt1" value="C" id="hindiOptC" disabled="true">
            सफेद: <input type="radio" name="opt1" value="D" id="hindiOptD" disabled="true">
            <br><label>प्रश्न संख्या 2. आपको कौन सा रंग पसंद है</label><br>
            लाल: <input type="radio" name="opt2" value="A" id="hindiOptA2" disabled="true">
            नीला: <input type="radio" name="opt2" value="B" id="hindiOptB2" disabled="true">
            भूरा: <input type="radio" name="opt2" value="C" id="hindiOptC2" disabled="true">
            सफेद: <input type="radio" name="opt2" value="D" id="hindiOptD2" disabled="true">
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <label>If Select English Langauge</label>
            <br><label>Q1. What is your favorite color</label><br>
            Red: <input type="radio" name="opt1" value="A" id="engOptA" class="eng" disabled="true">
            Blue: <input type="radio" name="opt1" value="B" id="engOptB" class="eng" disabled="true">
            Brown: <input type="radio" name="opt1" value="C" id="engOptC" class="eng" disabled="true">
            White: <input type="radio" name="opt1" value="D" id="engOptD" class="eng" disabled="true">
            <br><label>Q2. Which color you like</label><br>
            Red: <input type="radio" name="opt2" value="A" id="engOptA2" class="eng" disabled="true">
            Blue: <input type="radio" name="opt2" value="B" id="engOptB2" class="eng" disabled="true">
            Brown: <input type="radio" name="opt2" value="C" id="engOptC2" class="eng" disabled="true">
            White: <input type="radio" name="opt2" value="D" id="engOptD2" class="eng"disabled="true">
        </fieldset>
        </body>  
        </html>
```

Comment: Good Solution, but this is an example only, my real data have 45 question in each language, and display in both languages but activate only selected language data only, so can I use loop method in JavaScript?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, i have used loop in javascript as well as some little change in my code of input radio after that  code is working fine as per my requirement. Again Thanks a lot for your suggestions.